Why is node.js streams pipeline running my asyncGenerators in series?
I have an async generator that does something like this:
async function * fetchPaths() {
  const urls = await getUrls()
  for (const url of urls) {
    const paths = await fetch(url)
    for (const path of paths) {
      yield path
    }
  }
}

I then call this function like so:
  for await (const path of fetchPaths()) {
    await submit(path)
  }

I want these two async functions fetch and submit to run parallel to each other but not overwhelm each other. So it seemed like pipeline was the perfect fit - as I understand it, it can take AsyncGenerators as arguments, and handles the buffering and back pressure. It does work, but when I use it like so, it will still run them in series (e.g. await on fetch then wait for all the calls to submit to finish before calling the next fetch...
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises')

async function run() {
  await pipeline(
    fetchPaths(),
    async function(source, { signal }) { // also not clear on what to do with `signal`
      for await (const path of source) { // `source` is the fetchPaths generator?
        await submit(source)
      }
    }
  )
}

This is somewhat unexpected, since in my mind it seems like pipeline would just keep calling the iterator's next method and just handle the buffering if the destination was too slow, and keep it under the watermark. I read through the Node.js learning module on back pressure and I understand the concept but it's light on details about pipeline, and using AsyncGenerators in pipeline. Am I supposed to create a custom Readable and Writable class for the producer and consumer? Am I missing something else?

I found this repository which seems to suggest that yes, you would need to implement Readable for pipeline to be able to help with data flow and back pressure: https://github.com/MattMorgis/async-stream-generator/blob/master/index.js
However, the extensive documentation on streams reveals that there is a nice method for wrapping an AsyncGenerator in a Readable class, which makes the first argument to the pipeline trivial:
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises')
const { Readable } = require('node:stream')

async function run() {
  await pipeline(
    Readable.from(fetchPaths()),
    async function(source, { signal }) { 
      for await (const path of source) { // `source` is now a `Readable` stream
        await submit(source)
      }
    }
...

This was closer to what I wanted, but would behave in a way that seemed like it would only buffer 1 read chunk ahead of time (like having a highWatermark of 1)
I wrote a subclass of Writable that did the trick:
class WritableAsync extends Writable {
  /**
   * Class that creates a Writable stream that calls to an async function
   *
   * @see {@link https://nodejs.org/en/learn/modules/backpressuring-in-streams}
   * @see {@link https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#an-example-writable-stream}
   * @param {(any) => Promise<void>} asyncFn
   * @param {WritableOptions} writableOptions
   */
  constructor(asyncFn, writableOptions) {
    super(writableOptions)
    this._fn = asyncFn
  }

  _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this._fn(chunk)
    .then(() => {
      callback()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // let's not break the stream if the call fails, ymmv
      log.error(`error calling function ${this._fn?.name}`, err)
      callback()
    })
  }
}

Back pressure was handled automatically, as I could observe it when I adjusted the WritableOptions.highWatermark setting.
Putting it all together resulted in this elegance:
async function run() {
  await pipeline(
    Readable.from(fetchPaths()),
    new WritableAsync(submit, { decodeStrings: false, highWaterMark: 10 })
  )
}

